# How to load images using HttpClient API

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have one requirement. I need to access one of our servers (web site) and need to read the content using the URLs and render it on the browser.

In our Application, I am using HttpClient API to access the web pages of one server (http://10.x.xxx.87). I am able to get html content/ web pages in the form of HttpResponse of HttpClient API. The content is sent from my application to the client, where the content is rendered in the browser.

Some of the lines from response,

```
href="/web/common/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"

href="/web/common/css/login.css" type="text/css

href="/web/common/css/overlay.css" type="text/css"
```

This href is pointing to the server I am referring from my application. I think this href location is trying to find the images or css files in my local server. I want the images to be read from the server which is I am accessing from my application.

How to solve this issue ? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. When the client request for the following image, `href="/web/common/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"`, I am using servlet to read the response from other website.